# Batch file - changing variable value in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have following code snippet

```
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set b=123
    for %%f in (.\input\*.mgc) do (
       set "b=%%~nf"
       echo %b%
    )
```

I am expecting it to output file name with no extension but I always get "123". I concluded it has something with late expansion but not quite sure where the problem comes from. I have also tried with `echo !b!` but in that situation it outputs only "!b!"

Comment: A common misunderstanding as to how cmd.exe expands the value of the variable.  You need to reference the variable as `echo !b!`

Comment: @Squashman I wrote in my question that I have tried that but with no results

Comment: There are only two ways that `echo !b!` displays a literal `!b!` - either you didn't use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` or the one file in the input directory is called `!b!.mgc`. Those are literally the only two ways your output is possible. If `b` wasn't being set and delayed expansion was actually on like you claim it is, you'd see the error `ECHO is off.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `%b%` with `!b!` as explained [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php):

> The variable whose expansion should be delayed should be surrounded by exclamation marks instead of percent signs.

```
 setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
 set b=123
 for %%f in (.\input\*.mgc) do (
     set "b=%%~nf"
     echo !b!
 )
```

Comment: Apparently I didn't read the entire question, but this works fine for me in Windows 10.

Comment: You just posted exactly the same code I used in my question yet said my code did not work in Windows 10 for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in hard evidence.  I can't see you execute the code or if you are obfuscating the code at all so here is me executing your code.  It works just like I said.

```
C:\BatchFiles\SO>type testing.bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set b=123
for %%f in (.\input\*.mgc) do (
        echo %%~nf
        set "b=%%~nf"
        echo !b!
)
pause
C:\BatchFiles\SO>dir /b .\input\*.mgc
testfile.mgc

C:\BatchFiles\SO>testing.bat
testfile
testfile
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\BatchFiles\SO>
```

Comment: What OS are you using?